# SQL pesquisa dentro do mês atual

Tags: sql, data, pl-sql

Eu estou fazendo uma pesquisa dentro desse mês. Tem outra forma de pesquisar dentro do mês sem precisar ficar mudando a data?

Por exemplo: *and v.emissao >= TO_DATE('2022-10-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and v.emissao < TO_DATE('2022-11-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')*

quando muda o mês eu tenho que passar date por date, mudando o mês.

Comment: V_emissao between trunc(sysdate,'mm') and last_day(sysdate) ... Se v_emissao nao contem a hora

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado mestre!!!

Answer (score 0):

Olá,
Se for Oracle, tente usar as  funções de data.

Exemplo para pegar o ultimo dia do mês:
select sysdate, last_day(sysdate), last_day(to_date('2006-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd'))
from dual;

para primeiro dia do mês use:
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM') FROM dual

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).